# Phalcon constructor with parameters

Tags: parameters, constructor, model, phalcon

Phalcon does not accept constructors with parameters.
How can I go around that?

I want to be able to pass a value to the model to use it after.

I would like to do something like

```
class Students extends Model
{
    public function onConstruct($people, $subjects)
    {
        // do stuff ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Either you implement a custom setter or use the initialize() method. You can't override the constructor because it's final in Phalcon's Model class. You might also create static factory methods with parameters of your choice which return new model instances.

Comment: Setter did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of model classes has been [changed in version 2.1](https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/phalcon-2-1-beta-released), to allow you to pass an array of initialization data:

```
$customer = new Customer(
    [
        'name'   => 'Peter',
        'status' => 'Active',
    ]
);
```